# Use shell directly on ranger doesn't take bashrc in account

Tags: arch-linux, ranger, kitty

I'm on archlinux using ranger as my main file manager. Also I'm using Kitty as my terminal. In my configuration, i just replaced the diff by putting a :

```
alias diff="kitty +kitten diff"
```

Inside my .bashrc file And that works. But when i try to run the command :

```
:shell diff %f %c
```

Inside ranger (by pressing !), it runs the normal diff, not kitty +kitten diff.
Is there a way for ranger to take this in account?

Comment: I'm not sure `:shell` invokes bash by default (it may be `/bin/sh`) but even if it does, it looks like it does so *non-interactively*. See for example [custom shell commands not executed in ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/issues/1770).